# Create new columns to indicate column name's position inside another string vector (with dplyr, purrr, and stringr)

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, purrr

Given this example data:

```
require(stringr)
require(tidyverse)

labels <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")
n_rows <- 4

df <- 1:n_rows %>%
  map(~ data.frame(
      block_order=paste(sample(labels, size=length(labels), replace=FALSE),
                        collapse="|"))) %>%
  bind_rows()

df
  block_order
1 foo|bar|baz
2 baz|bar|foo
3 foo|baz|bar
4 foo|bar|baz
```

I want to generate a column for each string in `labels`, which takes the value of the position of that string in the `|`-separated sequence in each row.

Desired output:

```
  block_order foo bar baz
1 foo|bar|baz   1   2   3
2 baz|bar|foo   3   2   1
3 foo|baz|bar   1   3   2
4 foo|bar|baz   1   2   3
```

I've been trying different variations in a `dplyr`/`purrr` setup, like this example, where I `map` in each value of `label`, and then attempt to get its position in `block_order` using `match` on `str_split`:

```
labels %>%
  map(~ df %>%
        transmute(!!.x := match(!!.x, str_split(block_order, 
                                                "\\|", 
                                                simplify=TRUE)))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

But that produces unexpected output:

```
  block_order foo bar baz
1 foo|bar|baz   1   5   2
2 baz|bar|foo   1   5   2
3 foo|baz|bar   1   5   2
4 foo|bar|baz   1   5   2
```

I'm not really sure what these numbers represent, or why they're all the same.

If anyone can help me figure out (a) how to achieve my desired output in a `dplyr`/`purrr` framework and (b) why the proposed solution here gives the output it does, I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need to for other reasons, you don't have to fully split the string if you just identify the location of the first match for each value of `labels`, which `regexpr` will give you. `map`ping over `labels` will give a list with one element for each string in `labels` (so it's a quick iteration), which you can then `pmap` `rank` over to get indices. Using the `*_dfr` version to simplify the results to a data frame and cbinding to the original,

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

labels <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")
df <- data_frame(block_order = replicate(10, paste(sample(labels), collapse = "|")))

labels %>% 
    map(~regexpr(.x, df$block_order)) %>% 
    pmap_dfr(~set_names(as.list(rank(c(...))), labels)) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    block_order   foo   bar   baz
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 baz|foo|bar    2.    3.    1.
#>  2 baz|bar|foo    3.    2.    1.
#>  3 bar|foo|baz    2.    1.    3.
#>  4 baz|foo|bar    2.    3.    1.
#>  5 foo|bar|baz    1.    2.    3.
#>  6 baz|foo|bar    2.    3.    1.
#>  7 foo|baz|bar    1.    3.    2.
#>  8 bar|baz|foo    3.    1.    2.
#>  9 baz|foo|bar    2.    3.    1.
#> 10 foo|bar|baz    1.    2.    3.
```

If you prefer stringr/stringi to base regex, you could to the same thing by changing the `regexpr` call to `str_locate(df$block_order, .x)[, "start"]` or `stringi::stri_locate_first_fixed` in the same arrangement.

Comment: Whoa. This is some advanced s**t.  Could you explain the pmap/set_names/rank? , or link to simplified example of set_names/rank?

Comment: The `map` of `regexpr` generates a list of vectors of the character index of the first match for that label in `block_order`. `pmap` iterates in parallel over those vectors, `rank`ing each triple to turn them from indices (e.g. `c(5, 1, 9)`) to ranks (`c(2, 1, 3)`). The `set_names` and `as.list` is so the results can be rbinded into a data frame by the `*_dfr` version of `pmap`, which can handle named lists.

Answer (score 5):

We can split the 'block_order' by `|`, loop through the `list` of `vector`s using `lapply`, get the index with `match`, `rbind` the `vector`s and assign it to create new columns

```
labels <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")
df[labels] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df$block_order, "|",
         fixed = TRUE), match, table = labels))
```

---

Or similar idea with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_split(df$block_order, "[|]") %>%
       map(~ .x %>% 
              match(table= labels)) %>% 
      do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
      as_tibble %>% 
      set_names(labels) %>%
      bind_cols(df, .)
#   block_order foo bar baz
#1 foo|bar|baz   1   2   3
#2 baz|bar|foo   3   2   1
#3 foo|baz|bar   1   3   2
#4 foo|bar|baz   1   2   3
```

---

Another option would be to use `separate_rows`, reshape it to 'long' format and `spread` it back

```
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>%
    separate_rows(block_order) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    mutate(ind = match(block_order, labels), labels = factor(labels, levels = labels)) %>%
    select(-block_order) %>%
    spread(labels, ind) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
position_counter <- function(...) {
  row = list(...)
  row %>% map(~which(row == .)) %>% setNames(row)
}

df %>%
  separate(block_order, labels) %>% 
  pmap_df(position_counter)
```